# Problem converting PHP file to Prepared statements

Tags: php, flutter, mysqli

I'm trying to convert PHP file to Prepared statements. The original file is as follows and it is 100% working before modification:

```
<?php

include 'connt.php';

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$Name = $obj['Name'];

$loginQuery = "select * from Users where Name = '$Name' ";
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $loginQuery));
if ($check) {
    $check['result'] = 'Login Matched';
    $SuccessMSG = json_encode($check);
    echo $SuccessMSG;
} else {
    $InvalidMSG = array("result" => "Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again");
    $InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);
    echo $InvalidMSGJSon;
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

In the above code, I am checking the data if it matches or not by using the flutter language code:

```
Future CheckName() async {
    setState(() {
      visible = true;
    });
  //  var url = 'https://///////////////.php';
    var data = {'Name': nameController.text};
    var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
    Map<String, dynamic> message = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (message['result'] == 'Login Matched') {
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Main()));

    } else {
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });
      _showMyDialog();

    }
  }
```

Now after modifying the php code as follows:

```
<?php

include 'connt.php';

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$Name = $obj['Name'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name=?"; // SQL with parameters
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $Name);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
$user = $result->fetch_assoc(); // fetch data

if ($result) {
    $check['result'] = 'Login Matched';
    $SuccessMSG = json_encode($check);
    echo $SuccessMSG;
} else {
    $InvalidMSG = array("result" => "Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again");
    $InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);
    echo $InvalidMSGJSon;
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

After modification as above on the code. Now it works, but even if the name is wrong, it works correctly, it does not check if the name is present or not.

How to convert the first file from PHP in a correct way to Prepared statements or can solve the existing error?

Comment: You probably want to check `if($user)` instead of  `if($result)`

Comment: Hello, brother. Yes, the problem has been solved. I don't know how that happened. I'm sure I had tried this possibility before. @aynber

Comment: Hello brother, I have made Prepared statements. Is there a mistake in my work please inform me @Dharman

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood what you were asking for. The only problem I see is the typo that aynber pointed out. Other than that good job

Comment: @Dharman, The Question's Author's Problem Has Been Solved Without Any Answer. So    Now What's the next steps, Does stack allow the question which doesn't need any answer to solve or fix the prob..

Comment: @MUFAzmi We close such questions as typo/unreproducible. The system will delete it after 10 days